# How do I access the property of an object that is a string?

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I have an object which I need to convert from a string to a float in a before hook:

```
{ '$near': 
   { '$geometry': { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
     '$minDistance': '0',
     '$maxDistance': '10000'
   }
}
```

How do I access the $near property if its a string? I need to convert the values inside 'coordinates' from a string to a float.

```
console.log(location['$near']);
```

Doesn't work

Comment: Where is `location` comes into picture? Please share more info

Comment: @Issac Name of the object

Comment: Is said `location` on the global scope? Just making sure it doesn't collide with [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Comment: @ASDFGerte It's available on context.params.query on a FeathersJS before hook

Comment: What exactly is in `coordinates`?

Comment: @Nick coordinates: [ "144.982", "-37.864" ]

Comment: what does `console.log(location)` yield?  can you assign the object to a variable called something other than *location*?

Comment: So how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
let thelocation = { '$near': 
   { '$geometry': { type: 'Point', coordinates:  [ "144.982", "-37.864" ] },
     '$minDistance': '0',
     '$maxDistance': '10000'
   }
};
let coords = [parseFloat(thelocation.$near.$geometry.coordinates[0]),
              parseFloat(thelocation.$near.$geometry.coordinates[1])];
console.log(coords);
```

Output:

```
Array [ 144.982, -37.864 ]
```

Comment: Tried that - error:  TypeError: Cannot read property '$near' of undefined

Comment: The problem is your variable name, `location` has special meaning in a browser. Try changing the name (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

Using `vanillaJS` you can access the coordinates as below

```
let location = { '$near': 
   { '$geometry': { type: 'Point', coordinates: [{pointX: "1.23", pointY: "4.56"}] },
     '$minDistance': '0',
     '$maxDistance': '10000'
   }
}

location['$near']['$geometry']['coordinates'] //[{"x":"1.23","y":"4.56"}]

location['$near']['$geometry']['coordinates'].forEach(cor =>{
    console.log(cor.pointX);
  console.log(cor.pointY)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`location` is generally reserved to the browser.  Try using another variable name.  Also, keys in an object are all strings, so there's no special way of accessing it, other than the method you've already used (key-accessor or dot-notation):

```js
let _location = {
  '$near': {
    '$geometry': {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [1,2]
    },
    '$minDistance': '0',
    '$maxDistance': '10000'
  }
}

console.log(_location['$near']['$geometry']['coordinates']);
```

Comment: I already asked whether `location` was on the global scope in the comments for exactly that reason - but apparently it is not. I am guessing by now though that the part that actually leads to the problem is not in the question - but i do not know feathersjs so i cannot be certain.

Comment: @ASDFGerte so you did... if this is server-side I agree and I’m curious if the state is being mutated. This question should be closed as it cannot be repeated or not enough information given